# Playing Vimeo video in iOS Webview

Tags: ios, video, wkwebview, vimeo

this is the sample app to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/Rakshit91/Vimeo-Webview-Player

when the video ends the navigation bar and the status merges. the navigation bar goes under the status bar. the status bar overlaps the navigation bar.

this happens only when the controls in the video are hidden. this does not happen when the controls are showing and the video ends.

this happens in iPhone devices without notch

you can see the video here
https://youtu.be/ToONidWqMu0